# Why we use identity layer in ResNet?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

As I understand Resnet has some identity layer that their task is to create the output as the same as the input of the layer. but what is the use of this work? What is the benefit to add layers like this?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The sole purpose of creating ResNet architecture was to fix the problem of degrading/ saturating accuracy in deeper network which was caused by vanishing gradients as a primary reason . Identity layer or skip connections help prevent this problem since it is very easy for a layer to learn a linear function where input is equal to the output i.e f(x) = x . Now ResNet performed a lot better than other architectures and one reason as specified by Andrew Ng in his course is that skip connections learn the function f(x) = x very easily and if you are lucky then they sometimes learn that function plus other features which is beneficial for the network in extracting out final features.

Comment: Thank you for your good expression. But I need to know what is the benefit of adding a layer like this. when we have a network by 20 layers and now, for example, we add 5 layers that they get input and generate the same data as input for the output. now we have a 25 layer network that seems that 5 layers do nothing for us. what is the benefit of this 5 layer in this new network?

Comment: You might want to watch this video once : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYth6EbBUqM for better understanding.